# How do I Set Default Azure Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I was added as a co-administrator to another Azure account.  Now, when I log into the Azure portal, or use any of the Visual Studio integration, the default directory is the other account, not mine.

How do I set my default directory, so that I'm using my original account by default.

I looked through my account settings and all of the directory settings and I can't find anything to set this.

This is specific to Azure portal, as soon as I signed in to the Azure portal it should set my default account.

Comment: Did you try changing the directory in the Azure Portal Subscription Filter menu?

Answer (score 7):

From Azure portal you can click on your name from top menu. Then select "switch directory" option. Once it shows all the directory you can find default directory option in the same menu.[image: Please refer below image]

Answer (score 3):

The UI seems to have changed in the three years since Harish's answer.  As of August 2022 I don't see an option "Set your default directory".  Instead I see "Startup directory: [current startup directory name] (change)":

[image]

Changing the startup directory did the trick for me.

Comment: The URL for this page was https://portal.azure.com/#settings/directory for me! Not sure if it's ever org-specific for some folks.